Citizenship, child custody and child support - ghosted parent
I am Asian living in SEA, my French visa has run out. My husband is French and living in France. Our marriage was registered in France.
We have a newborn. My husband visited us when our child was born, and registered my child's birth here but not yet with the French embassy. So my child is not recognized as French.
He has since ghosted us and refused to answer any messages or emails.
Can I get a lawyer in France to ask for issues regarding my child?

Requests for legal advice aren't allowed here. Questions about hypothetical children abandoned by their French fathers would be, however.

I don't know where you are, but there is an international system called Reciprocal Enforcement of Maintenance Orders (REMO) which allows you to claim maintenance from overseas (UK gov page). Most SE Asian countries don't seem to be members though. Maybe there is French law.

You can get a lawyer in France to seek legal advice. You don't need to be in France to get legal advice from a French lawyer. All you need is a phone, probably an email address, and a way to send payment to the French lawyer such as a credit card.
You'll have to rely on the French lawyer to learn if you need to come to French to register your child's birth in France or to take other legal action such as a lawsuit to seek child support.
